# Concurrecy issues with multiple instances of an object

Tags: java, multithreading

the documentations always deals very explicitly with the issues of using one instance of an object with more than one thread.

However what do I need to know when there are some threads that have their own instance at the same time? Which interference could occur? How do I handle members like `SimpleDateFormat` that are quiet expensive to create?

Thanks
Mike
[;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If code from each thread is accessing different instances (objects) of the same class, that is not a problem; unless, of course, *those* objects are accessing shared objects, such as class static objects.

As the documentation for `SimpleDateFormat` states:

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

One way of keeping separate instances for each thread would be to use a [`ThreadLocal`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) object to keep track of separate instances.

Answer (score 3):

If each thread has it's own instance, and you don't use statics, then you are pretty safe :-)

No concurrencies issues !

Answer (score 1):

With respect to SimpleDateFormat, which as you point out is not threadsafe, you can instead opt to use the commons class [FastDateFormat](http://www.isocode.cn/pku-repo/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4-javadoc/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html) which is threadsafe and can be shared.

In more general terms, if you are sharing objects amongst threads always ensure that they are marked as threadsafe - the docs should always indicate this. If they are not threadsafe you will need to either limit concurrent access to them (e.g. via locks/synchronisation) or use multiple instances (one per thread). Generally, if you don't, you risk corrupting shared data/state with indeterminate consequences.

Answer (score 0):

It seems "most people" use a thread-local date format. Something like:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> dateFormat = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
     @Override public DateFormat initialValue() {
         return new SimpleDateFormat("fm/ts/tr", Locale.US);
     }
};
```